# Detect increasing divergence between two cumulative sums

Tags: pandas, scipy, correlation, cumulative-sum, cumulative-line-chart

I'm trying to think of some way to detect increasing divergence between two cumulative sum distributions. For example, I have data that looks like this: [image]

I tried exploring correlation coefficients and their p-values, but they were not sensitive to in the increasing distance. Does anyone have any tips on how to statistically (or otherwise) approach detecting patterns like this?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at "metrics", "statistical metrics", or "distance metrics".

Comment: More context/tags might help.  Are you using `numpy`, `pandas`, some other `stats` module?  You've plotted something, with what?

Comment: using pandas and scipy.stats, will add